# Separating datetime between 2 datetime columns by separate rows and separate time value by 24 hours

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I am working with 2 `datetime` columns (`PreviousUp` & `Downstart`), I want to separate these columns by each date and time the machine was up and working in that day in minutes/hours.

I do have a calendar table, but it has only date but no date time or time, should I alter that table too to get an outcome?

I trying to get the following output for some days but cannot get a crack of it.

[image]

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: How did you get 1455 minutes? It's possible only if Downstart is PM, not AM

Comment: Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: @Denis, the asset can be down even for a month too. It all depends upon how serious the issue is or availability of the parts for the particular asset. So Downstart can be AM and PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose:

1. Slice StartTime and EndTime by daily rows using separate function (main effort):

```
= (Source as table, StartTimeColumn as text, EndTimeColumn as text) =>
let  
    Source = Source,
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{StartTimeColumn, "__StartTime__"}, {EndTimeColumn, "__EndTime__"}}),
    #"Added ListOfDates" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "__Dates__", each List.Transform({Number.From(Date.From([__StartTime__]))..Number.From(Date.From([__EndTime__]))}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Expanded ListOfDates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added ListOfDates", "__Dates__"),
#"Changed ListOfDates" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded ListOfDates",{{"__Dates__", type datetime}}),
    #"Fix __StartTime__" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed ListOfDates", each [__StartTime__], each 
if Date.From([__StartTime__])=Date.From([__Dates__]) then [__StartTime__] else Date.StartOfDay([__Dates__]),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"__StartTime__"}),
    #"Fix __EndTime__" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Fix __StartTime__", each [__EndTime__], each 
if Date.From([__EndTime__])=Date.From([__Dates__]) then [__EndTime__] else Date.EndOfDay([__Dates__]),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"__EndTime__"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Fix __EndTime__",{"__Dates__"}),
    #"RestoreType Datetime" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"__EndTime__", type datetime}, {"__StartTime__", type datetime}}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"RestoreType Datetime",{{"__StartTime__", StartTimeColumn}, {"__EndTime__", EndTimeColumn}}),
    Result = #"Renamed Columns1"
in
    Result
```

[image]

2. Calculate duration in minutes (minor effort):

```
let
    Source = SliceDurationDaily(SourceTable, "Previousup", "Downstart"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "DurationMinutes", each Duration.TotalMinutes([Downstart]-[Previousup])),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"DurationMinutes", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

File with example available for download **[here](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/tree/ef13b029cd0c93ac6b693504103af8379d9d5c5b/Answers)**

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me. Attached is the image after the transformations applied.
There are cases where the machine/asset available to run without any downtime or maintenance. Example 110015 was up from 06/2017 to 08/2023 without going into maintenance. So, I would need all the dates between and hours the asset was up by each date.


https://imgur.com/a/VZmmgiY

Hopefully I make sense this time.

Comment: @VJ4407, it works for example in question body. Please improve your question (data sample example) - it will save time for everyone. P.S. It shouldn't be a just a screenshot - please use attached file or copy/paste ready example

Comment: @VJ4407, solution updated. Please check. P.S. I changed PreviousUp date in source data

Comment: Thanks @Denis, that did work. I got the data in the format I needed.
Sorry, I was not able share the file as I have not done before- will learn that too.

Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"assetnum", Int64.Type}, {"Previousup", type datetime}, {"Downstart", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each List.Transform({Number.From(Date.From([Previousup]))..Number.From(Date.From([Downstart]))}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Minutes", each
    if Date.From([Previousup])=Date.From([Downstart]) then Duration.TotalMinutes([Downstart]-[Previousup]) else
    if Date.From([Date])=Date.From([Downstart]) then Duration.TotalMinutes(Time.From([Downstart])-#time(0,0,0)) else
    if Date.From([Date])=Date.From([Previousup]) then Duration.TotalMinutes(#time(23,59,59)-Time.From([Previousup])+#duration(0, 0, 0,1)) else 1440)
in #"Added Custom1"
```